# iPhone - How to catch if the app is terminated (to update the badge icon)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events, process, kill

I'm setting :

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
}
```

in my application delegate but the badge is never updated... What can be the problem ?

**How may I do to update that badge when the app is killed (phone shutdown, taskbar app kill, app killed by the system because of a memory overload, ...) ?**

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on that line and double check it's actually getting called when you kill the app from the taskbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is terminated in the background, it does not get an opportunity to clean up after itself. The app is already suspended when backgrounded; when killed it is just removed from RAM. Your badge updates need to happen before that time.

[From the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html):

> **Suspended**
>   The app is in the background but is not executing code. The system moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before doing so. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not execute any code.
>   When a low-memory condition occurs, the system may purge suspended apps without notice to make more space for the foreground app.

Also:

> applicationWillTerminate:—Lets you know that your app is being terminated. This method is not called if your app is suspended.

Answer (score 1):

Throw an `NSLog(@"App is being terminated.");` into your `-applicationWillTerminate:` method.  I think you'll find that this method isn't being called when you are terminating the app the way you are.

You could set the application's badge icon during the app's normal execution or when the app is launched.

Comment: Right, not called. But the only moment I need to do things is when app is killed from running processes.

Comment: Do you not know ahead of this time what the icon's badge number should be?  You can change the badge number as much as you want while the app is running, because the user won't see the icon until they leave your app.  Therefore, if you change it in advance, the effect will be the same as if you had changed it at quit time.

Comment: My badge reflects the fact that the app is not loaded (anymore) in memory. So if you have an idea to achieve this goal...

Answer (score 0):

Please go over the [app lifecycle documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3) as below

Also try and see which of the below methods are being called

```
applicationWillResignActive:
applicationDidEnterBackground:
```