# How to remove iOS app icon badge when the app terminates?

Tags: ios, swift, badge, usernotifications

I want to set the iOS app icon badge to zero (which removes the badge on the icon) when the app terminates.  (...with Swift 4, iOS 10.x, 11.x)

In my ViewController I successfully requested local notification like this:

```
@objc func requestLocalNotification() -> Bool {
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    var result = true

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        if granted {
            result = true
        } else {
            result = false
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

And I successfully set the app icon badge with this:

```
@objc func notifyBadge(_ badge: Int) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.badge = badge as NSNumber

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
```

I can remove the badge when the app starts with this in AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    return true
}
```

It seemed to make sense to try to do it here when the user double taps the home button:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}
```

But it does not work.

I tried to use the shared application object instead of the passed application parameter:

```
UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
```

There are similar questions (and answers) on SO to reset the app icon badge but I only found 1 that pertains to doing it when the app is terminated by the user:

[iphone how to catch if the app is terminated to update the badge icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070358/iphone-how-to-catch-if-the-app-is-terminated-to-update-the-badge-icon)

But that question is over 5 years old and was not actually answered with a solution.  Perhaps someone has figured out a way to do it since then?

Comment: First, a question - why? You probably have your reasons, but if nobody else does this (I'm making an assumption) why should your app go against everything else? Having said that - `applicationWillTerminate`? If that's not what you need - **and** you've given enough specifics - how about `applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` or `applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)`? Please, explain specifically why none of these three suffice.

Comment: The problem you have is that `applicationWillTerminate` will not be called if you app is in the background.  I don't think there is a way around this because you are trying to use the badge icon for something it was not designed for.

Comment: @dfd - Why? Because since the user terminated the app the badge info is no longer valid.  (Similarly I've been annoyed by this with iMessage when accessed from multiple devices)   I tried using `applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` but that did not work either.  I use `applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)` to set the badge, so clearing it there is not practical.

Comment: @dfd - "why should your app go against everything else? " - Perhaps you know of an Apple doc that I've missed on the badge usage?  I'm not the smartest guy around and since it would be useful to me, I thought that it may be a useful trick for others.  When I see badges set on app icons, it tells me that there's something going on that I should investigate.  It's annoying to see a badge, click on the app icon, and find that there's no reason for it, or that it's wrong (25 on the badge, only 1 item in the app...)

Comment: @Upholder of Truth - "you are trying to use the badge icon for something it was not designed for" - Same reply to your comment.   Perhaps I've missed an Apple doc you can point out to me?  When the app gets terminated by the user, the badge info is not maintained anymore by the app in the background and will likely be wrong.  I just want to reset it to prevent the user from wasting time because the badge information is obsolete or wrong.

Comment: @ByteSlinger the badges are not designed to provide information relevant to the app only while it is running (foreground or background).  The badge is as up to date as when the app was last running and of course can be updated by a background notification.  Badges should also not be relied upon as they can be turned off.  What can have changed to affect the badge number while the app is terminated?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth - Thanks.  Where did you get this information?  What changed is the number of items implied by the badge.

Comment: To be fair it's not stated explicitly one way or another but you are finding out that there is no way to update them how you want.  However badges should be updated when an event affects them.  So you have a new transaction the badge number goes up.  The user deals with the transaction the badge goes down.  They are designed to be persistent whether the app is running or not and to be updated whether the app is running or not.

Comment: Regardless of it what it was designed for you have to be prepared for your app to be terminated without any notification.  So this means there is no way to guarantee the badge is set to zero every time the app is terminated.  Termination of an app without any notification to the app is most definitely by design.  That is one of the reasons that the advice for badges is to update them as soon as you can.

Comment: I guess it (for me) ends up with one baseline - what does the "average" user expect? There likely isn't an Apple doc describing how to have your badges behave (or not behave), but there are *very* few parties who can get away with going against user expectations - Apple being one of the obvious ones. You may not like how iMessage behaves - that's your right. It's also your right to zero out badges when an app terminates. But beware - if your average user isn't expecting that, there may be a price to pay.

Comment: @dfd  I fully agree with your views here.  You shouldn't fight the standard behaviour unless you have a really good reason to (and there almost never is).  Also in this case it can never work 100% how it is wanted to because an app can be terminated without notification thus giving the app no chance to zero the badge.  This could lead to an experience even worse than the one try to be solved as sometimes the badge would clear and others it wouldn't.